# retreive sample or a given amount of nodes with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, parsing, xmlstarlet

I'm working with an huge xml file and I need to get a sample of 500 nodes that are direct children of the root node. I know they are of the same type. I need to get all the children of those 500 nodes.

There is a way to do so in `xmlstarlet`?

I'd prefer using this specific package because I'm already using it to do other manipulations of the same file.

I tried looking in the help page of the package but couldn't find a way

Comment: @Cyrus

> I tried looking in the help page of the package but couldn't find a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/root/child[position() <= 500]" file.xml
```

- `sel` is the standard method for querying XML
- `-t` is always needed when using `sel`
- `-c` is for **c**opying
  *(whatever you select next in your xpath)*
- `/root/child` is the xpath
  *(replace with actual element names of obviously)*
- `[position() <= 500]` selects all nodes whose position (within the root element) is 500 or smaller.

Sometimes, I find that enclosing the path in brackets makes the selection work:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "(/root/child)[position() <= 500]" file.xml
```

but generally, the first method should be enough.

So, given an input of:

```xml
<root>
    <child>...</child>
    <child>...</child>
    ...
</root>
```

you would get:

```xml
<child>...</child><child>...</child>...
```

Mind you, no syntactically valid XML.

To separate with newlines, try a variation like:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/root/child[position() <= 500]" -c "." -n file.xml
```

- `-m` just **m**atches the xpath
  *(doesn't produce output)*
- `-c "."` copies the matched node
- `-n` appends a **n**ewline after each matched/copied node

---

### Part 2 - Select the first 'n' nodes of a certain type

Say, you want to get the first 3 apples from the following XML ('example.xml'):

```xml
<root>
    <apple>Braeburn</apple>
    <banana>Chiquita</banana>
    <apple>Granny Smith</apple>
    <plantain/>
    <apple>Cox</apple>
    <apple>Elstar</apple>
    <apple/>
    <apple/>
</root>
```

Then you could use:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/root/apple[position() <= 3]" -c "." -n example.xml
```

This again is basically the same as the previous example.
By adding the elementname ('apple'), you'll exclusively select the first three apple-nodes, as in the following output:

```xml
<apple>Braeburn</apple>
<apple>Granny Smith</apple>
<apple>Cox</apple>
```

Note how `<banana>Chiquita</banana>` and `<plantain/>` are left out.
They're not a direct `<root/>` child of type `<apple/>`.

##### Bonus:

Say you want to get the third apple, then you could use:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/root/apple[position() = 3]" example.xml
```

which would give you: `<apple>Cox</apple>`.

Or even shorter:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/root/apple[3]" example.xml
```

giving you the same result again.

Comment: Thanks @RvT the first solution (without parenthesis) worked like a charm.

I guess others could be interested in knowing how to retreive the first x elements af a specific type. If you know how to do that, can you consider adding it to your answer maybe?

Comment: Great to hear that @fbee.For your follow up question, could you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: For example, something like: Only select `<apple/>` from `<things><fruit><apple/><orange/></fruit><brands><apple/><McDonalds/></brands></things>` ?

Comment: that's not exactly what i meant. i adapt your example and rephrase the question.
 my question was to extract all the `<fruit>` nodes and all their children from `
<things>
  <fruit>
    <apple />
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <orange />
  </fruit>
  <brand>
    <apple />
  </brand>
  <brand>
    <McDonalds />
  </brand>
</things>
`

Comment: @fbee - so if I understand correctly:  if the input is `<things><fruit>...</fruit><brands>...</brands></things>`, you want to get just `<apple/><orange/>` ? _(the first x items in `<fruit>...</fruit>`  that is)_

Comment: the question is simpler than that. you have a `root` element with several children of type `apple`, `banana`, or `strawberry` and you want to get the first x nodes of type `banana`

Comment: @fbee I've added what I think you meant to my answer. I couldn't think of that many different bananas, so instead I used apples in my example (even though I'm not an Apple fanboy). Hope you don't mind. By the way: very grateful for being granted the accepted answer checkmark! Helped me pass the magical 50-point treshold. So thanks!

Comment: thanks to you! i accepted the answer since you provided a very good answer IMO to the first question. thanks a lot for providing a good one also to the second one ;)